# swift 3 find range of text starting with newline and ending with :

Tags: ios, swift3, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I have a swift 3 string that looks like this:

```
var str:String = "first name: \nkevin\nlast name:\nwilliams"
```

when printed, it looks like this:

```
first name: 
kevin
last name:
williams
xxx field:
408 878 2125
```

I want to find the ranges of fields that start with "\n" and end with ":" so I can apply attributes to them.  The field names may vary.  For example, I could have "phone number:" or "address:" in other cases.  how do I do this in swift 3?

an example is that I want to apply italics to the field names.  so a result might be:

*first name:* 
kevin

*last name:*
williams

*xxx field:*
408 878 2125

(The spaces after the colons got formatted out by stackoverflow).

Comment: Best to try and fully explain what you want to do to begin with... Are you applying the same attributes to each "word1 word2:" line? Or are you going to remove the newline chars? Maybe show an example of how you want the end result to look? *"The field names may vary..."* Will there be 3 "field names" - or could there be 10? 20? 50?

Comment: I've made the edits.  let me know if you'd like more clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versatile and suitable solution is *Regular Expression*

```
let string = "first name: \nkevin\nlast name:\nwilliams"

let pattern = "\\n?(.*):"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    for match in matches {
        let swiftRange = Range(match.rangeAt(1), in: string)!
        print(string[swiftRange])
    }
} catch {
    print("Regex Error:", error)
}
```

Btw: The first entry does not start with `\n`

Comment: Shouldn't it have -1
`NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count - 1)`

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard No, it shouldn't. The `length` parameter is not an index. But I updated the answer to the recommended Swift 4+ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach --- ***IF*** you know the format of your string will be

> fieldName1: \nfieldValue1\nfieldName2: \nfieldValue2\n etc

```
var str:String = "first name: \nkevin\nlast name:\nwilliams\nphone:\n212.555.1212"

var charsToClear = NSMutableCharacterSet(charactersIn: ":")
charsToClear.formUnion(with: .whitespaces)

let parts = str.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.trimmingCharacters(in: charsToClear as CharacterSet) }
```

This will split the string into an array of alternating *fieldName* and *fieldValue*. It will also trim extra whitespace and the colons on the way. So this example string would be turned into an array containing:

```
[ "first name", "kevin", "last name", "williams", "phone", "212.555.1212" ]
```

You could then create your attributed string(s) by stepping through the array, assigning any formatting you want.

As always, implement error checking as needed.